# Remote Windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, file-management, remote-access

I am looking for a program that would allow me to move or copy files on a remote computer that runs on Microsoft Windows 7. The program should be GUI, and conveniently allow to move or copy files.

E.g., it could look like Windows explorer (but would perform actions remotely, i.e. not on the local computer). Or it could look like some typical FTP clients, with both left or right panels showing files and folders from the remote computer.

I don't want to use VNC or other graphical desktop sharing systems.

Any license and price is fine.

Comment: No local<->remote transfers? Only remote?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ideally  only remote

Comment: And - I guess - you don't want the transfer happen via your PC for optimum performance? What OS does the local machine have?

Comment: Somehow one would need to connect to the remote Windows machine. Would you mind running an SSH server on the Windows machine?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I can run an SSH server on the Windows machine. The local machine runs on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I indeed would prefer the transfer not to happen via your PC for optimum performance, but I am still interested in solutions that do it anyway ( it's better than nothing )

Answer (score 2):

A good point was brought up by both Nicolas Raoul and Franck Dernoncourt, using the FileZilla Server Edition for copying and pasting data on one server requires the data to temporally be downloaded locally and then reuploaded, which will take significantly more time and not all that convenient either. Using a different FTP server with a module will circumvent this issue. To do this you'll need ProFTPD along with mod_copy and an FTP client that supports this protocol, I recommend WinSCP. All of these tools can be installed on Windows, ProFTP, however, will need to be installed through Cygwin.

## [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/) ([open source](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/))

> ProFTPD grew out of the desire to have a secure and configurable FTP
> server, and out of a significant admiration of the Apache web server.
>
> When the Project began, the most commonly used server was wu-ftpd.
> While wu-ftpd provides excellent performance and is generally a good
> product, it lacks numerous features found in newer Win32 FTP servers
> and has a poor security history. Many people, including the developers
> who work on ProFTPD, had spent a great deal of time fixing bugs and
> hacking features into wu-ftpd. Unfortunately, it quickly became clear
> that a complete redesign was necessary in order to implement the
> configurability and features desired.
>
> In addition to wu-ftpd, there are a few of other FTP servers available
> which are designed to be light-weight and secure at the expense of
> configurability. For example, Troll FTP is an excellent FTP daemon
> which is considerably more secure and less resource-intensive than
> wu-ftpd. Unfortunately, while it is quite suitable for basic FTP
> services, it does not offer the feature set required for more
> sophisticated FTP sites.
>
> ProFTPD is not a hack based on any other server, it's an independent
> source tree from the ground up. A number of well known and high
> traffic sites use ProFTPD.

#### [ProFTPD module `mod_copy`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_copy.html)

> The mod_copy module implements SITE CPFR and SITE CPTO commands (analogous to RNFR and RNTO), which can be used to copy files/directories from one place to another on the server without having to transfer the data to the client and back.

## [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

> WinSCP is a popular free SFTP and FTP client for Windows. Moreover, WinSCP is a powerful multi-functional tool that will improve your productivity.
>
> WinSCP can copy files between a local and remote computer using
> multiple protocols: FTP, FTPS, SCP, SFTP or WebDAV. On the one hand,
> WinSCP offers an easy to use graphical user interface; you can choose
> between Windows Explorer look and tabbed twin-panel interface like
> Norton commander. On the other hand, advanced users can automate
> WinSCP functionality using .NET assembly or simple batch file
> scripting.
>
> You will use WinSCP for all common operations with files. You can
> start editing a file directly from WinSCP, either using WinSCP
> internal text editor or using integration with your favorite external
> text editor. WinSCP operations are not limited to individual files;
> WinSCP offers several ways to synchronize your remote and local
> directories.
>
> WinSCP is available in English and many other languages. WinSCP is an
> open source software distributed free of charge under the terms of the
> GNU General Public License.
>
> [image: WinSCP Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to transfer files between the remote and the local computer, but only within the remote computer.

Comment: Moving a video from `MyRemoteFolder` to `MyRemoteFolder/SubFolder` should be immediate, but if going via FTP it would take ages, as the video would need to travel over the wire twice. FTP is just not a very good protocol for the asker's use case, unfortunately.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Great point, I've added a different FTP server along with a module and an FTP client that supports SITE, CPFR, and SITE CPTO commands, I think this solution should work for the OP, do you think so?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Also going to ping you, does this solution work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I did not know about these commands, sounds good!